# Is "less good" acceptable?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, comparatives

So I just read **"less good"** on a random chat...

I think this is incorrect, because *less good*'s "proper" word would be *worse*, but then I thought: if I say "I aced the exam", it's correct. If I say "I got all questions right on the exam", that's correct as well!

What forces me to use *worse* instead of *less good* then?

P.S. I have seen [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148647/is-less-bad-correct-usage-of-the-language), but the accepted answer is not the most upvoted one, so I don't know which to trust! Besides, none of the top answers provide a reference to back up what they say, so that's why I'm asking a new question.

Comment: I think the person is trying to be humble here when he says less good. I have seen people use this way of writing. Like one of the syrian refugee calling his fleeing journey to another country as just 'beyond stressful'. As it's not difficult to imagine, it would have been devastating but the words don't really capture deep agony.

Comment: Best/Better/Good/Less Good/Less Bad/Bad/Worse/Worst

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptable"? To whom? Yes, people use *less good*, and yes, other people understand them fine. There is nothing odd or unusual about *less good*. Why do you think there might be?

Comment: Certainly "less good" is "acceptable", and, as shown in some of jejorda's examples, better (or perhaps "more good") than "worse" in some circumstances (since it better conveys the intended semantics).  The reason for using "worse" in most cases is mainly that it's the commonly used term and hence less jarring to the reader than "less good".  In general one wants the reader to concentrate on the meaning being expressed, and not to be distracted by the choice of words, if that particular word choice serves no particular end, semantically.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Oxford Learners Dictionaries defines *worse*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/worse_1?q=worse) as, among other things, *less good*. So I suppose if OLD can use *less good*, so can we. Still, when comparing two good things I would say:

> A 90% score is good, but **not as good as** 100%.

My admittedly foreign ears don't like the sound of *less good than*. Google search concurs: *not as good as* beats *less good than* 6,000 to 1. This [English Grammar](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YBjT1ae8QeUC&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=%22less%20good%20than%22%20%22not%20as%20good%20as%22&source=bl&ots=xdKfXu1m4l&sig=gfmWH1NTx_wxMgUkQUzzMVtVL8s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAmoVChMIzc-avKrCyAIVBLgUCh1MSwxv#v=onepage&q=%22less%20good%20than%22%20%22not%20as%20good%20as%22&f=false) advises against *less good than* on the grounds that "[w]hen making negative comparisons less tends to be used only with multi-syllable adjectives."

Five months later I’m tremendously upset that fickle Google search has *not as good as* beating *less good than* 470 to 1 only. I swear it was 6000 to 1 when I first looked into it. Oops, it’s only 17 to 1 in the Ngram. But I include it below hoping it proves more constant. The first few pages of Google books search for *less good than* return almost only religion and philosophy books. They have *more good* too (my emphasis):

> A degreed property is a property that can be had in different degrees. Goodness is an obvious example of a degreed property. Something can be ***more good or less good than*** something else. [(David E. Alexander, *Goodness, God, and Evil*, Continuum, 2012, p. 115.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=mACpAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&dq=%22less%20good%20than%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4vN_S753LAhWK6RQKHdcmBikQ6AEIWzAK#v=onepage&q=%22less%20good%20than%22&f=false)

[image]

Comment: I upvoted this answer and the question. But we cannot deny the fact that it is used as the Jeff's answer indicates.

Comment: I think that's fair enough. I just wanted to point out that *not as good as* tends to be preferred to *less good than*.

Comment: Yes, I also believe *not as good* is better than *less good*.

Comment: @Jacinto that's a good point.

Comment: @Jeff Feel free to incorporate it in your own answer.

Comment: @Rathony or alternatively, it's less bad :-)

Comment: @Jacinto, *less good* sounds terrible to my native British ears as well. I would use *not as good* or *worse* (although the latter is implicitly negative as opposed to simply less positive).

Comment: @GeoffAtkins
 For example, "my Engilsh is far less good as you." It's a sentence you can't say "my English is far worse as you."

Answer (score 20):

There are differences in meaning between *worse* and *less good.*

Pancakes with butter taste good, but less good than pancakes with butter and syrup.

If I say that pancakes with butter taste worse than pancakes with butter and syrup, I mean that pancakes taste bad, and some toppings are more bad, rather than less good.

Comment: I disagree with this analysis.

Comment: @GEdgar why do you say so?

Comment: @AcidShout probably for the same reason I disagree with it; "worse" doesn't mean inherently or objectively "bad"... it is comparative. For example, if you run a 100m dash in 10 seconds flat, then 10.05, then 10.10, you are getting worse and worse, but that is still very fast/*good*.

Comment: *For example, if you run a 100m dash in 10 seconds flat, then 10.05, then 10.10...* That is why your athletics coach would probably make the *encouraging* remark that 10.10 was "less good" than your personal best time, not the *discouraging* remark that "your times were getting worse and worse". There is a  similar difference between "less bad" and "better".

Comment: Great example, I was having trouble thinking of that was acceptable. But to be fair, I think a less clumsy wording would be `Pancakes with butter taste good, but not as good as pancakes with butter and syrup`, ala Jacinto's answer.

Comment: I think that @alephzero's last sentence hits the nail on the head:  "pancakes with garbage and sewer water taste bad, but pancakes with garbage taste less bad" is perfectly fine (if unpalatable), while "pancakes with garbage taste better than pancakes with garbage and sewer water" just sounds wrong—at least to me.

Comment: The OP did not ask what the differences are between *worse* and *less good*. the question is whether *less good* is "acceptable".

Comment: The implication of this answer is that "less good" is acceptable. I agree that the answer would be a lot better if it said so explicitly. But I also agree with the main point of the answer, that there is a difference in connotation between "less good" and "worse" - I'm not sure if it is supported by official resources, but it is supported by practical usage, as far as I'm familiar with it at least.

Comment: Not common, but definitely acceptable. I think a better use of "_less good_" comes not when comparing two things (as most of the examples have) but when comparing two _changes_ from a "current thing"... Starting from "_plain pancakes are OK_", you can then say "_pancakes with butter and syrup are good_" and "_pancakes with butter are less good_".  Both changes are an improvement (hence _worse_ could have the wrong connotation), but one isn't as good an improvement as the other.  (There are, of course, several other ways of phrasing this avoiding "less good", e.g. "not as good").

Comment: I think the phrase "less good" is semantically similar to the widely accepted "not unlike". If something is not unlike something else, it's not really _like_ that thing but it's also not accurate to say it's _different. If some is "less good" than something else, It's not _as good_ as that thing, but it's also not _bad_.

Comment: I disagree that you automatically mean that if something is worse than something else then it is bad however the word "Worse" certainly does carry negative connotations which could put people in a negative frame of mind... but then saying a is less good than b is also sounds rather negative compared to b is better than a, however not to the same extent as worse.

Comment: I feel that in the UK we'd not say less good, but instead say *not as good as*. I can't think of any situation I'd say X is less good than Y.

Answer (score 6):

"Less good" is a rather uncommon phrase; it's usually used incorrectly by people that have a weak command of the English language (at least, in the United States of America). Of course, you *could* construct a sentence where "less good" is perfectly appropriate. This occurs when you're comparing two things that are good (things that are done for some benefit), but one is of a lesser degree than the other.

> Saving money later does *less good* than saving money earlier.
>
> CPR does *less good* than avoiding an accident.

In this case, "less good" is equivalent to "is not as good as" (with some other minor word changes). In this context, "good" is basically a stand-in for a type of quantity (thanks to [@LessPop_MoreFizz](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/16962/lesspop-morefizz) for the comment).

The usage of "less" here is the same as we might compare two actual quantities: "5 is *less* than 10". Less is a comparison of two quantities, so you should actually have two different things that can be compared in a quantifiable manner. "Less" typically goes between two things that are being compared.

For example, you should avoid *less good* in the following sentence:

> I did *less good* on that test.

In this case, you're not actually comparing two things, so you'd probably go with one of:

> I *didn't do well* on that test.
>
> I did *worse* on that test than my previous tests.

Or, in response to a question:

> How did you do on that test? *Not so good.*

Comment: When we refer to something that "Does good" (or "does less good"), 'good' is implicitly standing in for a *quantity* of sorts. You're right about which uses are appropriate, but you're not correct in your description of why.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Good point. I think I lost track halfway through. I'll amend this answer.

Comment: I think your last example is misleading because one wouldn't say "I did good on that test", but rather "I did well..." So the reason that sounds wrong is not because of the use of "less good" instead of "worse", but because of "good" instead of "well".

Comment: I like your first two examples. "Good" is a noun there, whereas the other answers had considered "good" as an adjective only. Would you then say "less good" is fine if "good" is a noun but not if it is an adjective?

Comment: phyrfox - Your answer still suffers from the problem raised by @LessPop_MoreFizz. You give an example of *CPR does less good than avoiding an accident.* and then you say *In this case, "less good" is equivalent to "is not as good as"*. That statement is incorrect. *CPR does less good than** is a valid statement, but 'good' in this case is a quantitative noun. 'less good' can be used for 'not as good as', but this meaning can only be when 'good' is used as an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard "less good" in two contexts:

1. People using it where "worse" or "not as good" would normally be used. Usually these are people for whom English is not their native language, but not always. It's not mainstream usage for native speakers in my experience.
2. People with excellent command of English using it ironically instead of "bad," for emphasis, e.g.:

   *"Okay, we use this ladder to get across. Just don't look down at the 12 storey drop. The ladder's old, but the wood's solid, we should be good."*

   *"But what if it breaks when we're half-way across?"*

   *"That would be...less good."*

> What forces me to use *worse* instead of *less good* then?

Just convention, nothing else, as with most language. Instead of "less good," we use "worse" or "not as good" depending on the sentence. Instead of "more good," we use "better."

Answer (score 2):

I'd say "x is less good than y" explicitly states that both of them are good while worse tells nothing about either one being good or bad so it is perfectly fine to use if you feel like it, but I'd think twice before using it in formal discussion where probably I'd use "x is not as good as y" instead

Comment: Welcome to the site, fellow noob! :) Just a word of caution here, I agree with your answer but the highest voted answer contains the same advice you're giving and preceded yours by about 15 hours. As such, I don't think you'll get a lot out of this answer. So before you write your answers, I advise you to check whether the answer that you want to give hasn't already been given.

Comment: @WolfieInu I don't think it is that close to it, I explained situations where using this construction may be desired and not just acceptable, and the OLD argument isn't perfect because it is simply one of two ways of defining "worse", the other one being "more bad", and proably more accurate in some cases. 
Unless you mean the pancake answer that I somehow missed earlier, and isn't top answer now, but it indeed is the same thing just said in less formal way

Comment: Fair enough! It would probably be more obvious if in your answer you state how it's different from existing similar ones, though. Formatting, links, and fewer run-on sentences would probably help in that regard. Not to be overly critical, just to help your answer's unique aspects stand out more. The better to earn upvotes with! :) (Edit: the answer I'm referring to is Jacinto's, and it's currently still the highest voted one)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "less good" if you are using *good* as an adjective. Its negative comparative form is "worse". If you are using *good* as the noun, however, you *could* say *"he did **less good** than he could have last night."* That would work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "It is true that you are a very good person, but your close-mindedness sometimes can make you less good." I think less good is not standard English, but there are moments you just want to use it and it is fine. Actually, English is not my native language. I am no expert.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Thank you for providing an answer. However this site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers.

Answer (score -6):

"Less good" is an odd phrase pandering to political correctness; "worse" carries undertones of criticism and we can't have that. Happily one can appease the thought police without butchering the language.

> Pancakes with butter taste good, but pancakes with butter and syrup taste even better.

Same thing, in a positive direction.

Comment: I think this actually has some element of truth to it. I have heard people use "less good" and "not as good as" as euphemisms. E.g. `Your paper was . . . not as good as it should have been.`

Comment: Unsurprisingly the thought police don't like being called out :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with "thought police", and everything to do with there being multiple ways to express an idea in English, which is _a good thing_. This answer is a rant without evidence.

Comment: I dislike political correctness as much as the next man, but I fail to see how it applies to preferred pancake toppings.