# 'Less good' vs 'worse'

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

Garner's fourth , page 263, reads

> *Depend* typically takes *on* (or, **less good**, *upon*). When a clausal complement follows the verb, to omit the on is a casualism—

Is *good* here an adverb?

Why not use *[worse](https://oed.com/oed2/00287305)* instead of *less good*?

Comment: "less good" means still valid but not as good as the alternative. "worse" might suggest wrong or bad. (This is my supposition at least.) I'd parse "less good" as an adjectival phrase modifying the word "upon", but you could use an adverb to modify "takes" (e.g. you might say "takes *on* or, less commonly, *upon*" in this position).

Comment: Though not a common usage, 'less good' is used to avoid the pejorative flavour of 'worse'. 'Good' here might be a value of 90% say, 'slightly less good' 80%, 'less good' 60%. 'A (or worse B)' would normally only be used when A is pretty poor.

Answer (score 1):

***Less good*** means that you go from ***good*** to ***not so good***, but still good (we are still in the "sphere" of good).

***Worse*** means that you go from something ***bad*** to something that is ***even more so*** (therefore, there is no *good* category in the sentence).

There is plenty of information on that in this [EL&U answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/280038/407211), so I won't harp on.

As for the syntax, have no doubt that ***good*** here is part of an adjectival phrase and not an adverb. In fact, ***good is always an adjective***. [Grammars](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/adjectives-adverbs/good-v-well/) will tell you so, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/good) will tell you so, and [this answer on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/101886/125959) will acknowledge it too.

I would argue that ***less good*** is an adjectival phrase [quantifier adverb "less" + adjective "good"] which modifies ***upon*** (***upon*** *is less good than **on***).

If it had modified a possibly elided noun  like ***choice*** or ***use***, an article would have been necessary:

> *Depend* typically takes *on* (or, [***a***] less good [***choice***], *upon*).

Comment: [https://books.google.es/books?id=T7v9DQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT316&dq=%20Maradona%20was%20worse%20than%20Pele&hl=es&pg=PT316#v=onepage&q=Maradona%20was%20worse%20than%20Pele&f=false](_In Italy everyone was arguing about whether I [Maradona] was better or worse than Pelé_). Logically, neither Maradona nor Pele were bad players.

Comment: If are not **as good as** Maradona, you can either be **better** or **worse**. This sentence is different from the sentence of the OP.

Comment: [**WORSE**. (adj.) Used as the comparative of bad, evil, ill, or as **the opposite of better**.](https://oed.com/oed2/00287305)_ BETTER https://oed.com/oed2/00021245

Comment: Exactly my point. In this sentence about the football players, "worse" is used as the **opposite** of "better". In the OP we are talking about comparatives.